# Like button Ajax in Ruby on Rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, social-media-like

I have a Ruby on Rails project with a model `User` and a model `Content`, among others. I wanted to make possible for a user to "like" a content, and I've done that with the [acts_as_votable](https://github.com/ryanto/acts_as_votable) gem.

At the moment, the liking system is working but I'm refreshing the page every time the like button (link_to) is pressed.

I'd like to do this using Ajax, in order to update the button and the likes counter without the need to refresh the page.

In my `Content -> Show` view, this is what I have:

```
<% if user_signed_in? %>
  <% if current_user.liked? @content %>
      <%= link_to "Dislike", dislike_content_path(@content), class: 'vote', method: :put %>
  <% else %>
      <%= link_to "Like", like_content_path(@content), class: 'vote', method: :put %>
  <% end %>
  <span> · </span>
<% end %>

<%= @content.get_likes.size %> users like this
<br>
```

The `Content` controller does this to like/dislike:

```
def like
    @content = Content.find(params[:id])
    @content.liked_by current_user
    redirect_to @content
end

def dislike
    @content = Content.find(params[:id])
    @content.disliked_by current_user
    redirect_to @content
end
```

And in my routes.rb file, this is what I have:

```
resources :contents do
    member do
        put "like", to: "contents#like"
        put "dislike", to: "contents#dislike"
    end
end
```

As I said, the liking system is working fine, but does not update the likes counter nor the like button after a user presses it. Instead, to trick that, I call `redirect_to @content` in the controller action.

How could I implement this with a simple Ajax call? Is there another way to do it?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can do so in various ways, the simple way goes like this:

### Preparations

0. Include Rails UJS and jQuery in your `application.js` (if not already done so):

   ```js
   //= require jquery
   //= require jquery_ujs
   ```
1. Add `remote: true` to your `link_to` helpers:

   ```erb
   <%= link_to "Like", '...', class: 'vote', method: :put, remote: true %>
   ```
2. Let the controller answer with a non-redirect on AJAX requests:

   ```
   def like
     @content = Content.find(params[:id])
     @content.liked_by current_user

     if request.xhr?
       head :ok
     else
       redirect_to @content
     end
   end
   ```

### Advanced behaviour

You probably want to update the "n users liked this" display. To archieve that, follow these steps:

1. Add a handle to your counter value, so you can find it later with JS:

   ```erb
   <span class="votes-count" data-id="<%= @content.id %>">
     <%= @content.get_likes.size %>
   </span>
   users like this
   ```

   Please also note the use of `data-id`, not `id`. If this snippet gets used often, I'd refactor it into a helper method.
2. Let the controller answer with the count and not simply an "OK" (plus add some information to find the counter on the page; the keys are arbitrary):

   ```
   #…
   if request.xhr?
     render json: { count: @content.get_likes.size, id: params[:id] }
   else
   #…
   ```
3. Build a JS (I'd prefer CoffeeScript) to react on the AJAX request:

   ```coffee
   # Rails creates this event, when the link_to(remote: true)
   # successfully executes
   $(document).on 'ajax:success', 'a.vote', (status,data,xhr)->
     # the `data` parameter is the decoded JSON object
     $(".votes-count[data-id=#{data.id}]").text data.count
     return
   ```

   Again, we're using the `data-id` attribute, to update only the affected counters.

### Toggle between states

To dynamically change the link from "like" to "dislike" and vice versa, you need these modifications:

1. Modify your view:

   ```erb
   <% if current_user.liked? @content %>
     <%= link_to "Dislike", dislike_content_path(@content), class: 'vote', method: :put, remote: true, data: { toggle_text: 'Like', toggle_href: like_content_path(@content), id: @content.id } %>
   <% else %>
     <%= link_to "Like", like_content_path(@content), class: 'vote', method: :put, remote: true, data: { toggle_text: 'Dislike', toggle_href: dislike_content_path(@content), id: @content.id } %>
   <% end %>
   ```

   Again: This should go into a helper method (e.g. `vote_link current_user, @content`).
2. And your CoffeeScript:

   ```coffee
   $(document).on 'ajax:success', 'a.vote', (status,data,xhr)->
     # update counter
     $(".votes-count[data-id=#{data.id}]").text data.count

     # toggle links
     $("a.vote[data-id=#{data.id}]").each ->
       $a = $(this)
       href = $a.attr 'href'
       text = $a.text()
       $a.text($a.data('toggle-text')).attr 'href', $a.data('toggle-href')
       $a.data('toggle-text', text).data 'toggle-href', href
       return

     return
   ```

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the answer. I've done exactly what you said above (put the JS in the scaffold created `contents.js.coffee`) but when I click the link, the number doesn't update in real time. It just updates after a refresh...

Comment: Did you `//= require content` in your `application.js` (or `//= require_tree .` for that matter)?

Comment: Yes, I did `//= require_tree .`

Comment: My bad, the event callback has the parameters `status` and `data` swapped, I'll update the answer.

Comment: How could I change the text in the button (and the action) along with the count number?

Comment: What I want to do is to change from "Like" to "Dislike", updating also the controller action that is called. How do I do that?

Comment: That's questioned in my question, so if I create a new post it will be repost. Could you edit your answer to help me?

Comment: Found the error. You're calling `toggle-text` instead of `toggle_text`. Same for `toggle-href`. Also, there's a `)` missing at the end.

Comment: At the end, what I said is not correct. Something is missing for it to work. Update your answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: Found the main problem: `remote: true` was missing in the `link_to` helper. Of course, the CoffeeScript error had to be fixed, too (see [revisions](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/24221646/revisions) for details).

Comment: I would use a POST instead of PUT.