# remote: true Ajax call works in local server but not in Heroku

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, heroku

This is my first question to Stack Overflow.

I'm writing a rails app which will be running in Heroku. User can like / unlike posts. This action is registered by recommendable gem's Sidekiq workers.

I'm using Public Activity to track activities of posts, hence a.trackable.id is the post.id...

I have the ajax call in following code working in localhost :

public_activity/posts/_create.html.erb :

```
<%= link_to "Beğenmekten Vazgeç", unlike_post_path(a.trackable.id), data: {id: a.trackable.id, toggle_text: 'Beğen', toggle_href: like_post_path(a.trackable.id)}, class: 'like_toggle', remote: true %>
```

in my Posts Controller :

```
def like
  @post = Post.find(params[:id])
    current_user.like(@post)

  if request.xhr?
    render json: { id: @post.id }
  else
    redirect_to user_profile_path(@post.user)
    flash[:notice] = "Ajax hatası"
  end
end
```

and _create.coffee file is

```
$(document).on 'ajax:success', 'a.like_toggle', (status, data, xhr) ->
  $("a.like_toggle[data-id=#{data.id}]").each ->
    $a = $(this)
    href = $a.attr 'href'
    text = $a.text()
    $a.text($a.data('toggle-text')).attr 'href', $a.data('toggle-href')
    $a.data('toggle-text', text).data 'toggle-href', href
    return
```

essentially, it changes the like / dislike text as described in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24221367/like-button-ajax-in-ruby-on-rails) question.

In my gemfile, I have

```
gem 'jquery-rails', '~> 4.0.3'
```

and in my application.js file I have ;

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery-ui
```

I cleaned and precompiled assets in production.

It is working OK in localhost. But in Heroku, I can't seem to get it working.

Here's the server log :

```
Processing by PostsController#like as HTML 
Parameters: {"id"=>"1"}
User Load (1.7ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
Post Load (1.6ms)  SELECT  "posts".* FROM "posts" WHERE "posts"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
Redirected to https://emoportal.herokuapp.com/user_profiles/1
2015-04-24T16:14:15.287Z 3 TID-osdy24n1g Recommendable::Workers::Sidekiq JID-986cd2fea4f7bfffd55849b0 INFO: start
2015-04-24T16:14:15.368Z 3 TID-osdy24n1g Recommendable::Workers::Sidekiq JID-986cd2fea4f7bfffd55849b0 INFO: done: 0.082 sec
User Load (1.3ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
Completed 302 Found in 680ms (ActiveRecord: 6.7ms)
```

Any help or ideas will be much appreciated. 
Thanks.

Comment: Did you restart Heroku? (had problem with that before)

Comment: Do you have this in your Gemfile: 
gem 'rails_12factor', group: :production

Comment: Yes I do. Exactly as you've written.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it. The problem was jquery_ujs was not present in Heroku environment, despite all precompilation and other stuff.

In config/environments/production.rb file, I set `config.serve_static_files = true` and I did `RAILS_ENV=production rake assets:precompile` then pushed to repo to Heroku.

That was it.